# How to get Python error as C string?

Tags: python, string

I have a C++ application that embeds the Python interpreter. It calls PyImport_Import to load scripts. I need a way of getting any syntax errors as C strings. For example, if the script uses a undefined function, I would like an error saying something like 'Function xxx is undefined.' How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyErr_Occurred](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_Occurred) lets your C code check whether an exception has been raised, and, if so, what type; then, [PyErr_Fetch](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_Fetch) lets you fetch all details (as Python objects), and you can get the string representation of the error instance with the usual high-level call [PyObject_Str](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Str) (just the same as `except Exception, e: ...str(e)...` in Python code).